# RSA decrypt failing between Java and browser using web crypto api

Tags: javascript, java, cryptography, rsa, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to get encrypted response from server using RSA public key. Cipher is generated on server side but decoding on client side fails. Web crypto API throws DOM Exception.

Java server:

```java
byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(body.exponent);
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(body.modulus);

BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);

RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(spec);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal("hello".getBytes())
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherBytes);
```

Browser:

```js
const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {
    name: 'RSA-OAEP',
    modulusLength: 512,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
    hash: 'SHA-256',
  },
  true,
  ['encrypt', 'decrypt'],
)

const jwk = await window.subtle.exportKey('jwk', key.publicKey);

const response = await fetch('/foo/bar', { method: 'post', body: { exponent: jwk.e, modulus: jwk.n } });

const body = await response.text();

const binary = window.atob(body);
const bytes = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
  bytes[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
}

await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
  { name: 'RSA-OAEP' },
  key.privateKey,
  bytes.buffer,
); // returns undefined throws the error
```

EDIT: After further research, I found that:

1. (Obviously) cipher generated by web crypto api has no problem with decoding.
2. Returning byte array itself from server side doesn't help.

Comment: what's the exact error

Comment: It just throws DOMException

Comment: Looks like crypto.subtle doesn't like a "moduluslength" less than 2048

Comment: with `hash: 'SHA-1'` you could have minimum `modulusLength: 1024` - with `hash: 'SHA-256'` it seems the minimum is `modulusLength: 2048` - can't see, other than in googles horrific documentation, a `modulusLength: 512` ever being used

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but this doesn’t fix the problem

Comment: so, you're still getting the DOMException if you change to `modulusLength: 2048`

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: what is the value of `binary.length`

Comment: It's 256 when I set `modulusLength` to 2048

Comment: I‘d recommend to debug / decrypt the returned encrypted content here https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=RSA_Decrypt('-----BEGIN%20RSA%20PRIVATE%20KEY-----','','RSA-OAEP','SHA-1') just to verify that your used  key pair is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Webcrypto-side you are using

```
name: 'RSA-OAEP',
hash: 'SHA-256',
...
```

to instantiate the algorithm. On Java side you "just" instantiate the cipher with

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

but that is the synonym for

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
```

You need to use  those lines to instantiate the Webcrypto algorithm:

```
    Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
    OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpecJCE = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, oaepParameterSpecJCE);
    ciphertextByte = encryptCipher.doFinal(plaintextByte);
```

Security note: a keylength of 512 is **UNSECURE**, kindly use a minimum of 2048 bits key length.